# Parsing fix xml and mapping fields to column names

Tags: fix-protocol

I have some FIX reference data and I want to map fields to column names.

For example,

8=FIX.4.29=46535=d34=249=CX52=20131209-11:54:48.79556=ICAP67=182=900320=91322=77c945fd-f4b2-4c64-80db 912b6f7af287323=4393=900146=1311=515243309=TE0101S14E0060XXB305=H9801=I9802=EUI9803=S1 SUB 10Y9804=EUR9805=Y9806=Y9889=N9887=09807=259878=259879=3509906=259880=259881=3509907=259810=Y9811=0.259910=-19812=BPS9813=N9814=2I667EAA09815=201409209816=109851=609852=ITRX9853=N9883=IDB9884=A9896=Y9899=N9903=N9914=N9876=N9905=N10=140

If I were to paste this data into the parser I want to be able to insert the value for say tag 9802 to a row within a specific column.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Your whole plan will fall apart for fields that are within repeating groups.

Comment: Anytime you post FIX messages, you should edit them so we can see the field separators (which are non-printable characters and thus usually get lost in a copy/paste).  It's very hard to tell where a field ends and the next begins.

Comment: Your parser could be a wrapper written over the portion of reading a FIX message of any FIX engine. Not sure how tricky this might be, but seems like an option.